# Freeform text inside DRF_YASG generated docs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Is there a way to add freeform text to docs generated through drf_yasg? I can't see an obvious explanation in their docs.

I just want to add a few sections of introduction text.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that drf_yasg supports markdown in the description!! Like:

```
SchemaView = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="My API",
        default_version="v0",
        terms_of_service="",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="support@example.com"),
        description="""
### Header

Some description text

- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3

#### Header
""",
    ),
    public=True,
    patterns=patterns,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
```

I didn't see this documented anywhere, though it might be. But that's exactly what I was looking for.